# SQL select by using limit or using program to fetch special records

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I am using php to get special records from Database.
which one is better?
1.

```
Select * From [table] Limit 50000, 10;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     //save in array, total 10 times
}
```

or
2.

```
Select * From [table];
$start = 50000;
$length = 10;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     if($i < $start+$length && $j >=$start){
          //save in array, total 50010 times
     }
}
```

In this case, which one should I use?

Which one using DB with less resources?

Comment: The first one is better. 1) as per the line of code. 2) as per the total number of data load.

Comment: #1 is better. MySQL is also better in aggregations. avoid PHP to do the calculations

Comment: In these two, the first is better, but actually  they both are not a good design,  jump 50000 is to much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which one is better?

Too vague: what is "better"?

> Which one using DB with less resources?

You're much better off with the first approach. It's efficient to select as little data as you need and no more. Selecting the whole table will force your script to use a lot more memory because all that data needs to be kept live

The best answer you'll get is: **test!**  You can run your queries multiple times in multiple ways and see for yourself. Just use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...` instead of the generic `SELECT...` to force the DB to restart the work from scratch. Measure how long it takes to run the query and process results

```
function wayOne(){
    //  execute your 1st query and loop through results
}
function wayTwo(){
    // execute 2nd query and loop through results
}

//Measures # of milliseconds it takes to execute another function
function timeThis(callable $callback){
    $start_time = microtime();
    call_user_func($callback);

    $microsecs = microtime()-$start_time; //duration in microseconds    
    return round($microsecs*1000);//duration in milliseconds
}

$wayOneTime = timeThis('wayOne');
$wayTwoTime = timeThis('wayTwo');
```

You can then compare the two times. Generally (not always) a process that takes significantly less time uses fewer resources